# Duplicity won't remove old backups, even after full backup

Tags: backup, duplicity

I just did a full backup with Duplicity using `--full-if-older-than 7D`. When I do a `duplicity remove-older-than 7D --force` now, I see the following:

```
Last full backup date: Sun Feb 23 12:19:43 2020 (just a few minutes ago)
There are backup set(s) at time(s):
...
...
...
Which can't be deleted because newer sets depend on them.
No old backup sets found, nothing deleted.
```

If I do a full backup, as I just did, shouldn't I be able to remove all older backups, that are older than 7 days? Or is this because my incremental backups, *that are newer than 7 days* (yesterday, for example), depend on the older sets?

Answer (score 0):

Check your backend. I was using `scp:` which did not support the `delete` of the four possible operations `get`, `put`, `list` and `delete` operations. I read the man page's A NOTE ON SSH BACKENDS section (specifically the paragraph "SSH pexpect backend") and then changed my backend to `sftp:` which solved the delete issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can read :

```
 --remove-older-than <time> [--force] <url>
              Delete all backup sets older than the given time.  Old
              backup sets will not be deleted if backup sets newer than
              time depend on them. Note also that
              --force will be needed to delete the files instead of just
              listing them.
```

The idea is that duplicity keeps the possibility to go back in time from the indicated time, and keep dependencies which can be older.

If you want to go back in time past 7 days and does full backup every 7 days, you may have the following backups :

```
D-7:inc
D-6:*full*
D-5:inc
D-4:inc
D-3:inc
D-2:inc
D-1:inc
```

Here, the D-7 backup must be preserved, but also the dependencies (D-13 which is full, and the following incremental backups).